# what was the correct way to update file for admin html module-backend?

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, product-images, image-upload

i want to change in file location :

> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/Uploader.php

but its core file. I'm changing MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT and MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH in this php file. where to update this file, the correct way .

i thinks i should in /var/www/html/app/code/Ves/Setup
there are some folders
block
controller
view
etc ..

is there something i need to to do?
please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

Please find below link it is similar to your question [How to override adminhtml phtml in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183129/how-to-override-adminhtml-phtml-in-magento-2).