# How to extend private function getTierPriceStructure($tierPricePath) in class AdvancedPricing

Tags: magento2

I am having some trouble here. I need to extend `private function getTierPriceStructure($tierPricePath)` in `class \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing`.

How do I achieve this?

PS: I am trying to add new field in `tier_price` section of product edit page.

[image]

This is what I want to do:

```
private function getTierPriceStructure($tierPricePath)
{
    //since below line is calling parent's private function, it will throw error.
    $result = $this->getTierPriceStructure($tierPricePath); //this is private function
    $newColumn = [
        'children' => [
            'record' => [
                'children' => [
                    'value_cost' => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                    'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                                    'dataType' => Price::NAME,
                                    'label' => __('Cost'),
                                    'enableLabel' => true,
                                    'dataScope' => 'value_cost',
                                    'addbefore' => $this->locator->getStore()
                                                                 ->getBaseCurrency()
                                                                 ->getCurrencySymbol(),
                                    'sortOrder' => 80,
                                    'validation' => [
                                        'required-entry' => true,
                                        'validate-greater-than-zero' => true,
                                        'validate-number' => true,
                                    ],
                                    'imports' => [
                                        'priceValueCost' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.value_cost',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $result = $result + $newColumn;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: No way. You need to duplicate this method in your extended class.

Comment: Then pretty much all the functions will be extended. Is there another way, maybe from `ui`?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri do you have this code? I'm trying to achieve the same functionality but my code not working: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/324309/21339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try a plugin after the public method `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AdvancedPricing::modifyMeta()` and manipulate the return value.

The return value should contain the complete array structure and you might be able to add your data to the right position. Since that is the only place the data is provided to objects from outside the class, it could work.