# Unable to update extra tier price column Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

[Edit]
[I have added code at git](https://github.com/developerapr/Gpsaleprice/tree/master)

I have created a module to create an additional column in tier price by the [following tutorial](https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-add-a-column-to-the-tier-price-in-magento-2-admin/) 
While creating new products its working fine, but while updating the products it's not working
It's throwing error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAllCustomersGroup() on null in /home/arun/raisahab/www/magentoProjects/magesm/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/TierPrice/AbstractHandler.php:75 Stack trace: #0
```

Update code:

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    namespace Arunendra\Gpsaleprice\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\TierPrice;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\Tierprice;
    class UpdatePriceHandler extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\TierPrice\UpdateHandler
    {
       /**
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        private $storeManager;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $attributeRepository;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool
         */
        private $metadataPoll;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\Tierprice
         */
        private $tierPriceResource;
    
        /**
         * @var FormatInterface
         */
        private $localeFormat;
    
        /**
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository
         * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement
         * @param \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\Tierprice $tierPriceResource
         * @param FormatInterface|null $localeFormat
         */
        public function __construct(
            StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
            GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
            MetadataPool $metadataPool,
            Tierprice $tierPriceResource,
            FormatInterface $localeFormat = null
        ) {
            parent::__construct($groupManagement);
    
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
            $this->metadataPoll = $metadataPool;
            $this->tierPriceResource = $tierPriceResource;
            $this->localeFormat = $localeFormat ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(FormatInterface::class);
        }
    
        /**
         * Perform action on relation/extension attribute.
         *
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface|object $entity
         * @param array $arguments
         * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface|object
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
         */
        public function execute($entity, $arguments = [])
        {
            $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get('tier_price');
            $priceRows = $entity->getData($attribute->getName());
            if (null !== $priceRows) {
                if (!is_array($priceRows)) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException(
                        __('Tier prices data should be array, but actually other type is received')
                    );
                }
                $websiteId = (int)$this->storeManager->getStore($entity->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
                $isGlobal = $attribute->isScopeGlobal() || $websiteId === 0;
                $identifierField = $this->metadataPoll->getMetadata(ProductInterface::class)->getLinkField();
                $productId = (int)$entity->getData($identifierField);
    
                // prepare original data to compare
                $origPrices = [];
                $originalId = $entity->getOrigData($identifierField);
                if (empty($originalId) || $entity->getData($identifierField) == $originalId) {
                    $origPrices = $entity->getOrigData($attribute->getName());
                }
    
                $old = $this->prepareOldTierPriceToCompare($origPrices);
                // prepare data for save
                $new = $this->prepareNewDataForSave($priceRows, $isGlobal);
    
                $delete = array_diff_key($old, $new);
                $insert = array_diff_key($new, $old);
                $update = array_intersect_key($new, $old);
    
                $isAttributeChanged = $this->deleteValues($productId, $delete);
                $isAttributeChanged |= $this->insertValues($productId, $insert);
                $isAttributeChanged |= $this->updateValues($update, $old);
    
                if ($isAttributeChanged) {
                    $valueChangedKey = $attribute->getName() . '_changed';
                    $entity->setData($valueChangedKey, 1);
                }
            }
    
            return $entity;
        }
    
        /**
         * Update existing tier prices for processed product
         *
         * @param array $valuesToUpdate
         * @param array $oldValues
         * @return bool
         */
        private function updateValues(array $valuesToUpdate, array $oldValues): bool
        {
            $isChanged = false;
            foreach ($valuesToUpdate as $key => $value) {
                if ((!empty($value['value'])
                        && (float)$oldValues[$key]['price'] !== $this->localeFormat->getNumber($value['value'])
                    ) || $this->getPercentage($oldValues[$key]) !== $this->getPercentage($value)
                ) {
                    $price = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                        [
                            'value_id' => $oldValues[$key]['price_id'],
                            'value' => $value['value'],
                            'percentage_value' => $this->getPercentage($value)
                        ]
                    );
                    $this->tierPriceResource->savePriceData($price);
                    $isChanged = true;
                }
            }
    
            return $isChanged;
        }
    
        /**
         * Insert new tier prices for processed product
         *
         * @param int $productId
         * @param array $valuesToInsert
         * @return bool
         */
        private function insertValues(int $productId, array $valuesToInsert): bool
        {
            $isChanged = false;
            $identifierField = $this->metadataPoll->getMetadata(ProductInterface::class)->getLinkField();
            foreach ($valuesToInsert as $data) {
                $price = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($data);
                $price->setData(
                    $identifierField,
                    $productId
                );
                $this->tierPriceResource->savePriceData($price);
                $isChanged = true;
            }
    
            return $isChanged;
        }
    
        /**
         * Delete tier price values for processed product
         *
         * @param int $productId
         * @param array $valuesToDelete
         * @return bool
         */
        private function deleteValues(int $productId, array $valuesToDelete): bool
        {
            $isChanged = false;
            foreach ($valuesToDelete as $data) {
                $this->tierPriceResource->deletePriceData($productId, null, $data['price_id']);
                $isChanged = true;
            }
    
            return $isChanged;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get generated price key based on price data
         *
         * @param array $priceData
         * @return string
         */
        private function getPriceKey(array $priceData): string
        {
            $qty = $this->parseQty($priceData['price_qty']);
            $key = implode(
                '-',
                array_merge([$priceData['website_id'], $priceData['cust_group']], [$qty])
            );
    
            return $key;
        }
    
        /**
         * Check by id is website global
         *
         * @param int $websiteId
         * @return bool
         */
        private function isWebsiteGlobal(int $websiteId): bool
        {
            return $websiteId === 0;
        }
    
        /**
         * Prepare old data to compare.
         *
         * @param array|null $origPrices
         * @return array
         */
        private function prepareOldTierPriceToCompare(?array $origPrices): array
        {
            $old = [];
            if (is_array($origPrices)) {
                foreach ($origPrices as $data) {
                    $key = $this->getPriceKey($data);
                    $old[$key] = $data;
                }
            }
    
            return $old;
        }
    
        /**
         * Prepare new data for save.
         *
         * @param array $priceRows
         * @param bool $isGlobal
         * @return array
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         */
        private function prepareNewDataForSave(array $priceRows, bool $isGlobal = true): array
        {
            $new = [];
            $priceRows = array_filter($priceRows);
            foreach ($priceRows as $data) {
                if (empty($data['delete'])
                    && (!empty($data['price_qty'])
                        || isset($data['cust_group'])
                        || $isGlobal === $this->isWebsiteGlobal((int)$data['website_id']))
                ) {
                    $key = $this->getPriceKey($data);
                    $new[$key] = $this->prepareTierPrice($data);
                }
            }
    
            return $new;
        }
    }
```

Comment: May be It's because your constructor does not match the parent Model constructor.

Comment: I have tried by updating the code but not working check code.

Comment: have you tried finding calling which method leads to this error ?