# Extra column in catalog_product_entity_tier_price not saving/updating in observer in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, tierprice

Trying to get this working in Magento 2.3

[Extra column in catalog_product_entity_tier_price not saving/updating in observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226627/extra-column-in-catalog-product-entity-tier-price-not-saving-updating-in-observe)

Progress so far

https://bitbucket.org/DominicWatts/tierpricing

Can get column to show but will not save.  Also if you manually edit in db value is wiped on next save if you change price or quantity.

Has anyone got this change working in Magento 2.3?

Comment: Can you add your observer code here?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get a solution working using the code example above. In the end I created an observer on admin product save which caught the post parameters and saved them to the database.

The three columns I added are:

- supplier_name
- supplier_price
- supplier_update

So bit different to my example in bitbucket

*Update*

As requested. It's not great code.  I just wanted to get the job out the door.

etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer instance="Xigen\NameCost\Observer\Backend\Catalog\ProductSaveAfter" name="xigen_namecost_observer_backend_catalog_productsaveafter_catalog_product_save_after"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer/Backend/Catalog/ProductSaveAfter.php

```php
<?php

namespace Xigen\NameCost\Observer\Backend\Catalog;

class ProductSaveAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    private $logger;
    private $request;
    private $productTierPriceInterface;
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterfaceFactory $productTierPriceInterface,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\TierPriceInterfaceFactory $tierPriceFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->productTierPriceInterface = $productTierPriceInterface;
        $this->tierPriceFactory = $tierPriceFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct(); 
        $params = $this->request->getPostValue();
        $dateFormat = "d/m/y";

        // print_r($params['product']['tier_price']);
        if(isset($params['product']['tier_price'])) {
            foreach($params['product']['tier_price'] as $tier) {

                if(isset($tier['price_id']) && isset($tier['supplier_price']) && isset($tier['supplier_name'])) {

                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
                    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
                    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
                    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_tier_price');

                    $select =  $connection
                        ->select()
                        ->from(['cpetp' => $tableName])
                        ->where('cpetp.value_id = ?', $tier['price_id']);

                    $existing = $connection->fetchRow($select);

                    if($tier['supplier_price'] != $existing['supplier_price'] || 
                       $tier['supplier_name'] != $existing['supplier_name']) {

                        try {   
                            $connection->beginTransaction();
                            $connection->update(
                                $tableName, 
                                [
                                    'supplier_name' => ((trim($tier['supplier_name']) == '') ? null : $tier['supplier_name']), 
                                    'supplier_price' => $tier['supplier_price'],
                                    'supplier_update' => date($dateFormat)
                                ], 
                                ['value_id = ?' => $tier['price_id']]
                            );
                            $connection->commit();
                        } catch(\Exception $e) {
                            $connection->rollBack();
                            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```