# How to override adminhtml template file in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, template, overrides

I want to override account.phtml file located at /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form

How can i do that?

Comment: please specify in which layout ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183129/how-to-override-adminhtml-phtml-in-magento-2 Check this link